# Providers, Routes and Navigators

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

We all know providers are scoped, if we insert a provider inside a route, then other routes will not be able to access that provider. In short, we have to put a provider above the root navigator (i.e., MaterialApp) to access it from two different routes.

The problem is I don't want to put the provider above the root navigator and I also don't want to use nested navigators just to access the providers in two different routes. How do you guys approach this problem? I want to know how other people in the community are tackling this problem.

Comment: Check Riverpod out - https://riverpod.dev